PyCharm won't let me import from folders cloned from github
I am experiencing a strange error that I don't know how to characterize.
I am trying to import a class from a subfolder, cloned from GitHub. But when I do from Awesome_Python_Games import class_to_import, it says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Awesome_Python_Games'
So, I tried to let PyCharm do the heavy lifting. Therefore, I placed the file in another folder I created in the home directory fold_1.fold_2 and it was detected. When I manually moved it into Awesome_Python_Games I was expecting PyCharm to refactors the import statement. This time, however, the refactor process involved deleting the import statement!
The folder Awesome_Python_Games was a git clone from here - https://github.com/OSSpk/Awesome-Python-Games
Here are some screenshots -
This gives an error -

This doesn't -

I found a similar post here, but even after following the instructions in the top-rated answer I couldn't get it to work.

are you forget to create and activate virtual env?

Have you told PyCharm to treat the root of the project as a Sources folder?

@Tanveer I don't see how that would help. Do let me know if I am not understanding something :)

The Folder Awesome_Python_Games is set as your root directory in Pycharm. Therefore, when you do from Awesome_Python_Games import class_to_import, it looks for Awesome_Python_Games in Awesome_Python_Games and does not find it.
To solve the problem, you need to set tbd_3 as your root directory. Right click on it then look for Mark Directory as  then click on Source Root.
This should solve your problem
